# Functions to format text for base R plotting

Tags: r, plot, text, figure, plotmath

Specifying text in a base R `plot()` with formatting such as italics / bold font / newline usually involves one or more of the following functions:

```
paste()
expression()
atop()
substitute()
italic()
```

Is there an intuitive explanation for the differences between these functions and when best to apply them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring to is the `plotmath` syntax.

To start off, let's make it clear that for a plotmath expression to be interpreted as such, you tell R it's an "expression" and that is why you need `expression()`.

So any time you want to use special symbols or formatting, like `italic()` and `atop()`, it's actually a part of plotmath and so you need to wrap it in an expression. eg:

```
plot(0, main = expression(atop(over,italic(under))))
```

[image: plot1]

If you've tried out `?italic` or `?atop`, you've probably noticed it takes you straight to the plotmath manual page, where a bunch of other functions are listed.

What about `substitute()` ? Well in my previous example, you'll notice I used strings directly to write 'over' and 'under', without putting them within quotes. This is because of the special `expression()` environment.
So if you need to put whatever is *inside* a variable in your text (rather than the variable name) then you put your expression inside a `substitute()` and give it the arguments. eg:

```
plot(0, main = substitute(atop(oo,italic(under))), list(oo='over2')))
```

[image: plot2]

Note that we don't put substitute around the expression block but replace it entirely.

Finally, where does `paste()` come in all this ? Well, paste is the glue (pun intended) with any text not dealt with by plotmath.

So if you need text before or after math symbols (or formatted text), you `paste()` things together *within* the expression (or substitute) environment. eg :

```
plot(0, main = substitute(paste("b4", atop(oo,italic(under)), aft),
                          list(oo='over', aft = 'after3')))
```

[image]

As before, if you want to paste the content of a variable, you need substitute.

And *Voilà* that's most of the plotmath you'll ever need!

For any other symbols, or functions, have look at `?plotmath`